# Android SDK manager throws an error when trying to install packages in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

i am about to install packages via Android SDK manager. i typed android in terminal and it redirects me to the android sdk manager but when i tried to install the package its throws a error that nothing was installed.

the error message in terminal:

(Android SDK Manager:12550): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1278 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Android SDK Manager:12550): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1323 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Android SDK Manager:12550): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1350 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Android SDK Manager:12550): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1606 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Android SDK Manager:12550): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1658 was not found when attempting to remove it

Comment: why no one is responding my question. I got really stuck on this since last two days. please help